# Remove group of rows when value is present in at least one of the rows

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, conditional-statements

I am trying to use dplyr to filter data. I would like to eliminate a whole group of rows if some rows contain a value, then a whole group should be removed.

The example data is shown below: E.g the Variable "name" contains a group of CE 10:0. The "SampleType" of this group is either "step" or "Blank". If there is a value "Blank" present in"SampleType" in group CE 10:0, then the entire CE 10:0- group should be removed.

So in this example, only the groups CE 10:3 and CE 11:1 would remain.

I cant get my head around this filtering function, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
fullname    name    intensity   SampleType  
step6-a-s   CE 10:0 11997.1 step  
step7-c-s   CE 10:0 8752    step  
step4-c-s   CE 10:0 6969.9  step  
Blank2-s    CE 10:0 2231.1  Blank  
step6-b-s   CE 10:0 3275.6  step  
step7-b-s   CE 10:0 4485.4  step  
step3-c-s   CE 10:0 4191.6  step  
Blank1-s    CE 10:0 4349    Blank  
step8-a-s   CE 10:0 8838    step  
step7-b-s   CE 10:1 6155.3  step  
step4-c-s   CE 10:1 5899.9  step  
Blank2-s    CE 10:1 3098.6  Blank  
step6-b-s   CE 10:1 2945.2  step  
step5-c-s   CE 10:1 1207.2  step  
Blank1-s    CE 10:1 4173    Blank  
step2-b-s   CE 10:1 3219.4  step  
step4-a-s   CE 10:3 3658.2  step  
step1-b-s   CE 10:3 4070    step  
step5-a-s   CE 10:3 2776.4  step  
step3-a-s   CE 10:3 4821.6  step  
step4-b-s   CE 10:3 4145.9  step  
step5-c-s   CE 11:0 7056    step  
step3-c-s   CE 11:0 6367.5  step  
step2-b-s   CE 11:0 6426.9  step  
step7-c-s   CE 11:0 5133.9  step  
Blank2-s    CE 11:0 4006.3  Blank  
step1-c-s   CE 11:0 3791.7  step  
step4-b-s   CE 11:1 5183.7  step  
step4-a-s   CE 11:1 3549.5  step  
step3-b-s   CE 11:1 2822.9  step  
step1-b-s   CE 11:1 2495.7  step
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a much simpler solution to this: first make the vector containing the names from rows with "Blank", and then in a second step use this vector for eliminating the groups with the corresponging names. Maybe not the most elegant method but it works

```
blanks_in_n_and_s_split <- n_and_s_split %>%
  filter(SampleType == "Blank")
species_in_blank <-  unique(blanks_in_n_and_s_split$name)
n_and_s_split_blankfiltered <- n_and_s_split %>% 
  filter(!name %in% species_in_blank)
```